# <select> to inherit the styles of the chosen <option>

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So I want a `select` dropdown menu, with each option being a different colour.

```
<select>
    <option value="blue" style="background-color:blue"></option>
    <option value="red" style="background-color:red"></option>
</select>
```

When a colour is selected, I want the `select` box itself to inherit the `background-color` of the option that was selected.

I know this can be done quite easily with javascript, I am wondering if there is a CSS solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this. Onchange event needs to be captured and color needs to be changed for select list

```
 <select name="select" onchange="this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
     <option class="Red" value="1">Red</option>
     <option class="Green" value="2">Green</option>
     <option class="Blue" value="3">Blue</option>
</select>

.Red{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.Green{
   background-color: #00ff00;
}
.Blue{
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LD8Dx/74/)

Comment: wont `select option` style any `option` elements found inside `select` elements?

Comment: still not sure if this will work - can you provide a jsFiddle or similar of what you propose?

Comment: Sorry, I may need to update my answer, Because we need to capture on change event of select list and change the color.

Comment: this works, but uses javascript - im guessing at thsi point there is no pure CSS solution - so have a tick